# VALGRIND: invalid read of size 8

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, valgrind

i have problems with valgrind,

i created this class:

```
class shop {

    private:
       vector<vector<string> > products_;

    public:
           shop(string ProductFile);
           FindMinPrice(string product);
}

    //method in the cpp file
    vector<string> shop::FindMinPrice(string product){
         string ProductName=(string)products_[0][0];

    }
```

i didn't write the entire code but its work fine with the GCC compiler.
when i run valgrind check it shows:
invalid read of size 8 
and in eclipse it send me to the ProductName line.

what is wrong with the design ? and how so that the GCC compile and run but VALGRIND collapse?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your `products_` vector of vectors is empty, meaning that the access of element `products_[0][0]` is undefined behavior.

The unfortunate thing about undefined behavior is that your program may appear to work, and may even complete without any visible problems.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using c-style cast in c++ is not a good practise.
2. Your shop method doesnt return any value.